# How i can show the social icons in one line for the aviator picture?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show the social media icon in one line like this
[image]

but it does not work for me which I have written the code it shows me a different result than what I expected if anyone knows my mistake so please help me with the new code I will be thankful to you.
This is the picture that I get as the result of the code
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Meet Our Team</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap and fontawesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



    <style>
        .our-team {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .our-team .pic {
            border-radius: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        .our-team .pic:before,
        .our-team .pic:after {
            content: "";
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 13px solid #e6e5e5;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .our-team .pic:after {
            border-color: #37b0f1 #e6e5e5 #e6e5e5 #37b0f1;
            z-index: 1;
            transform: rotate(-10deg);
            transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        }

        .our-team:hover .pic:after {
            transform: rotate(350deg);
        }

        .our-team img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .our-team .title {
            font-size: 26px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #222;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
            position: relative;
        }

        .our-team .title:after {
            content: "";
            width: 30px;
            height: 2px;
            background: #222;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        .our-team .post {
            display: block;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-style: italic;
            color: #777;
        }

        .our-team .icon {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
        }

        .our-team .icon li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .our-team .icon li a {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #e0e0e0;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #999;
            margin-right: 5px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        }

        .our-team .icon li a:hover {
            background: #37b0f1;
            color: #fff;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
            .our-team {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        }
    </style>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="our-team">
                                    <div class="pic"><img src="C:\Users\Muzamil Laptop\Downloads\Nmdcat_test.png"
                            alt=""></div>
                                    <h3 class="title">Williamson</h3>
                                    <span class="post">Web Developer</span>
                                    <ul class="icon">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook"></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-skype"></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
             
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="our-team">
                                    <div class="pic"><img src="C:\Users\Muzamil Laptop\Downloads\abc.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    <h3 class="title">Kristiana</h3>
                                    <span class="post">Web Designer</span>
                                    <ul class="icon">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook"></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-skype"></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
    </div>        





    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--FontAwsome CDN-->

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cf36fcc825.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Cant reproduce, even just crudely copy&pasted into a jsfiddle, this looks absolutely fine (tested in Chrome) - https://jsfiddle.net/oeka7uvz/

Comment: U can try to clear cash, and Ctrl+F5 on page view.

Comment: @laiju i am using chrome

Comment: @Andrew Sure i will try

Comment: @CBroe Thank you i have put your code and it works fine Thank you so much

Comment: But that was _your_ code to begin with, I didn't change anything about it ...

Comment: This is working fine is getting your expected output. the event I have trie Chrome, firefox, and edge alse. it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Meet Our Team</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap and fontawesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



    <style>
        .our-team {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .our-team .pic {
            border-radius: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        .our-team .pic:before,
        .our-team .pic:after {
            content: "";
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 13px solid #e6e5e5;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .our-team .pic:after {
            border-color: #37b0f1 #e6e5e5 #e6e5e5 #37b0f1;
            z-index: 1;
            transform: rotate(-10deg);
            transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        }

        .our-team:hover .pic:after {
            transform: rotate(350deg);
        }

        .our-team img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .our-team .title {
            font-size: 26px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #222;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
            position: relative;
        }

        .our-team .title:after {
            content: "";
            width: 30px;
            height: 2px;
            background: #222;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        .our-team .post {
            display: block;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-style: italic;
            color: #777;
        }

        .our-team .icon {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
        }

        .our-team .icon li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .our-team .icon li a {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #e0e0e0;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #999;
            margin-right: 5px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
        }

        .our-team .icon li a:hover {
            background: #37b0f1;
            color: #fff;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
            .our-team {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        }
    </style>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="our-team">
                                    <div class="pic"><img src="C:\Users\Muzamil Laptop\Downloads\Nmdcat_test.png"
                            alt=""></div>
                                    <h3 class="title">Williamson</h3>
                                    <span class="post">Web Developer</span>
                                    <ul class="icon">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook"></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-skype"></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
             
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="our-team">
                                    <div class="pic"><img src="C:\Users\Muzamil Laptop\Downloads\abc.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    <h3 class="title">Kristiana</h3>
                                    <span class="post">Web Designer</span>
                                    <ul class="icon">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook"></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-skype"></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
    </div>        





    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--FontAwsome CDN-->

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cf36fcc825.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code only answer are not considered as valid, please add some explanations on how did you fixed your problem